# How do I get at, and then remove the parent of an SKNode?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, parent, skspritenode

A `SKSpriteNode` has a parent, that's been randomly assigned, and isn't aware of who it is.

How does that `SKSpriteNode` find its parent, and then remove the parent from the scene, thereby removing itself and the parent?

Comment: Doesn't a SKNode have a parent property, which you could access directly? Or am i missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you read the documentation thoroughly, you would find a method called [`removeFromParent`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/sknode/1483119-removefromparent) in the `SKNode` class. Just call it:

```
yourSpriteNode.removeFromParent()
```

Alternatively, if you want to remove the node from its parent after a sequence of `SKAction`, you can use [`SKAction.removeFromParent()`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skaction/1417748-removefromparent).

```
let removeFromParentAction = SKAction.removeFromParent()
let sequence = SKAction.sequence([yourOtherActions, removeFromParentAction])
yourSpriteNode.run(sequence)
```

EDIT:

After reading your comments, I can guess that you probably did something like this:

```
// "cherry pick" an action
let action = AllMyActions.action1
yourSpriteNode.run(action);
```

Well, the way to solve this is to create an action like this:

```
let removeParent = SKAction.run { 
    [unowned self] in self.yourSpriteNode.parent?.removeFromParent() }
```

Put the above code just after the line where you cherry picked the action, and

```
yourSpriteNode.run(SKAction.sequence([action, removeParent]))
```

Comment: I want to remove the parent of an unknown instance from the within an action executed by the child. Not remove the child calling the action from the parent. You've answered a question I didn't ask.

Comment: @Confused Isn't there a parent property you can access? https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/sknode/1483080-parent Can't you use that?

Comment: I can't access the parent property from within where the Actions and their sequences are created, as they're written "generically" and the grabbed and run by the children.... so it's (seemingly) impossible to grab the parent whilst  working in this manner.

Comment: There is no "self" at the point where I'm writing the Actions. This is also annoying.

Comment: @Confused Can you show the part of your code where you create the actions?

Comment: The actions are created statically, inside a file that's not a class, and then plucked from there when needed... probably the wrong way to do EVERYTHING. They're globals/static... everywhere accessible so I can cherry pick from therm when I want.

Comment: Argh, you are a wonderfully intuitive and wise reader and understander of people and their doings. I think your `let removeParent = ... [unowned self] in self.yourSprite...` etc might do it. Can this work from inside the child node, if it doesn't have a references to itself?

Comment: To be honest, I never consider these reference cycle things. I just use unowned for all escaping closures. If it doesn't work, I'll just change it to weak and add ? to all selfs. @Confused

Comment: Wow. This is a comment full of wisdom. It will take me some time to understand, attempt and adopt this approach. But I'm liking it, a lot!

Answer (score 1):

suppose A is a SKSpriteNode , the you can check if it has a parent and if it has, you can remove it from view by removing from parent.

```
if let parentOfA = A.parent{
 parentOfA.removeFromParent()
}
```

Comment: How do I do this from `self'? In other words, how does a child query itself and then release its parent from its parent?

Comment: @Confused,  That is bad design,  a child should not tell a parent what to do.  This is the equivalent of you telling your mother to kill herself.  Instead the parent should recognize the child has died, and then decide to kill itself.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon be that as it may, is it possible?